# Probability that certain drawn pieces of paper having the same colour are in the same group

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

I have the following question:

I have 12 players and wrote their names on 12 pieces of paper.

I put the 12 pieces of paper in a box, but 2 pieces of paper were green-coloured, and the rest was red-coloured.

Blindfolded I divided the 12 pieces of paper into 4 groups, such that there were 3 pieces of paper in each group.

> What is the probability that the two green-coloured pieces of paper are in the same group?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say Arnold and Berhard were the two people who put their names on a green piece of paper. Arnold is a natural leader, and will take control of whatever team he's selected into. It will therefore be called the "A-team". Now, Arnold has two teammates, and there are $9$ people who are not on the A-team. So there are $11$ places for Bernhard, and $2$ of them are on the A-team. Thus, the probability that Bernhard joins the A-team along with Arnold is $\frac{2}{11}$.